# Como obtener el primer y último día de una semana específica

Tags: mysql-workbench

Buenas noches este código me sirvió para obtener el primer día de la semana y ultimo día de la semana a partir de la fecha actual(no esta todo codigo del procedimiento almacenado)

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `bsp_listar_turnos_semanal`()
BEGIN

```
SELECT      
t.Id_Turno,
m.Nombre, 
m.Apellido,
p.Nombre, 
p.Apellido,
t.Fecha_Programada,
t.N_Orden

FROM    turnos t
INNER JOIN  medicos m on t.Id_Medico = m.Id_Medico
INNER JOIN  pacientes p on t.Id_Pacientes = p.Id_Pacientes
WHERE t.Fecha_Programada between SUBDATE(now(),WEEKDAY(now())) and
ADDDATE(now(),6-WEEKDAY(now())) ;

END
```

mi pregunta es como obtener  el primer y último día de una semana ,ingresando cualquier fecha .Muchas Gracias espero se entienda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependiendo de si la semana comienza el domingo o el lunes, tienes que hacer el cálculo de un modo o de otro:

```
SET @theDate="2019-01-30";
SELECT
    DATE_ADD(@theDate, INTERVAL(1 - DAYOFWEEK(@theDate)) DAY) firstBeginSunday,   -- primer día (si semana comienza el Domingo)
    DATE_ADD(@theDate, INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK(@theDate) ) DAY) lastBeginSunday,  -- último día (si semana comienza el Domingo)

    DATE_ADD(@theDate, INTERVAL(-WEEKDAY(@theDate)) DAY) firstBeginMonday,        -- primer día (si semana comienza el Lunes)        
    DATE_ADD(@theDate, INTERVAL (6 -WEEKDAY(@theDate) ) DAY) lastBeginMonday      -- último día (si semana comienza el Lunes)
;
```

**Salida:**

```
firstBeginSunday     lastBeginSunday        firstBeginMonday     lastBeginMonday
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-01-27           2019-02-02             2019-01-28           2019-02-03
```

---

#### Fiddle

Ver código de prueba aquí: <kbd>**[`Demostración`](https://rextester.com/CWBR58275)**</kbd>

---

#### Dentro de la PROCEDURE

Para ponerlo dentro de la procedure, el código sería más o menos así:

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost
PROCEDURE bsp_listar_turnos_semanal(theDate) 
BEGIN
    SELECT      
        t.Id_Turno,
        m.Nombre, 
        m.Apellido,
        p.Nombre, 
        p.Apellido,
        t.Fecha_Programada,
        t.N_Orden
    FROM turnos t
        INNER JOIN  medicos m on t.Id_Medico = m.Id_Medico
        INNER JOIN  pacientes p on t.Id_Pacientes = p.Id_Pacientes
    WHERE 
        t.Fecha_Programada BETWEEN 
            DATE_ADD(theDate, INTERVAL (-WEEKDAY  (theDate)) DAY) AND        
            DATE_ADD(theDate, INTERVAL (6 -WEEKDAY(theDate)) DAY)
END
```

Y para llamarla le pasas una fecha válida en formato `YYYY-MM-DD` encerrada entre comillas:

```
bsp_listar_turnos_semanal('2019-02-01);
```

Comment: agradecido funciona perfectamente mi duda seria como adaptarlo a mi código

Comment: @GuidoBenicio realmente no lo adapté a tu código porque no entendí la lógica del mismo, si me lo explicas podría indicar cómo adaptarlo a tu código. No sé si lo que quieres es una consulta con un `BETWEEN` entre lo que sería el primero y el último día de la semana a partir de una fecha dada ¿? Tampoco es que tenga demasiada experiencia con procedures,  pero debes indicar si la fecha en la que hay que buscar la semana viene de fuera de la procedure (supongo que sí), en ese caso la misma tendría que recibir un parámetro.

Comment: @ A. Cedano asi ya que tengo  muchas fechas ingresadas y partir de una fecha dada conocer el primer ultimo dia de la semana para eso estoy utilizando stored procedure como el publicado.Gracias

Comment: @GuidoBenicio sería cuestión de que tu procedure reciba en parámetro el valor de `@theDate` y crees la consulta con el `WHERE` usando ese valor que habrá recibido en parámetro...

Comment: @ A. Cedano este es el codigo que acabo de editar a donde lo quiero adaptar no se si se entiende.Gracias

Comment: @GuidoBenicio ¿no te funciona así?  ¿Cómo lo estás llamando?

Comment: USE clinicav3;
CALL bsp_listar_turnos (2019-02-02);

Comment: @GuidoBenicio no tengo experiencia con procedures, pero creo que debes declararla indicando que recibirá un parámetro: `CREATE PROCEDURE bsp_listar_turnos_semanal(IN theDate DATETIME)`, luego, dentro de la procedure, en vez de `@theDate` usas `theDate` (sin la arroba) y la llamada normal, pasándole la fecha **pero entre comillas**: `bsp_listar_turnos_semanal('2019-02-02')`

Comment: @ A. Cedano    lo realice tal cual como me dijiste realizando esos cambios se ejecuto perfectamente.MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: @GuidoBenicio voy a poner el código con la procedure completa. Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.

Comment: @ A. Cedano    solo faltaria en el codigo en la parte de parametros        
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `bsp_listar_turnos`(in thedate datetime ) creo que ahi te di bien el voto positivo